# how to select a cell if it has certain value in column next to it

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel workbook with 3 sheets:

Sheet 1 and Sheet 2

> ```
> Columns A-G have text entered into them
> Column H is a selection of either 1,2, 3 or H from a drop down list
> Column I has numeric (currency) value entered into it (called year 1)
> Column J has numeric (currency) value entered into it (called year 2)
> Column K has numeric (currency) value entered into it (called year 3)
> Column L has numeric (currency) value entered into it (called year 4)
> Column M has numeric (currency) value entered into it (called year 5)
> Column N has numeric (currency) value entered into it (called years 6-10)
> ```

Sheet 3 consists of a table.

I need a formula that will pick up the figures and transfer and add them into Sheet 3.

So I need to know the total of Year 1 (column I) if column H reads a number 1 to transfer into a cell on sheet 3, and then into a different cell the total of year 1 (column I) if column H reads a number 2 etc..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This may suit:

> =SUMIF(Sheet1!H:H,1,Sheet1!I:I)+SUMIF(Sheet2!H:H,1,Sheet2!I:I)

*Edit* - and for other cell (!):

> =SUMIF(Sheet1!H:H,2,Sheet1!I:I)+SUMIF(Sheet2!H:H,2,Sheet2!I:I)

Adds totals from Sheet1 and Sheet2 of the sums of the row values in ColumnI where ColumnH contains the criterion (1 for one cell, 2 for the other) in the corresponding row.

[=SUMIF](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/sumif.php)